# How to access multiple dictionaries in list with Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a JSON file with multiple dictionaries within a list and I would like to access the 1st-10th key:value pair for a number of keys.  In the example below I would like to access only the first dictionary in each list and the key:value for Container Number.  I have tried indexing the dictionary values, but to no avail.

Here is my code, which returns all container numbers from all dictionaries, how can I implement this so I can assign a variable to the container numbers for the first dictionary in each list.

My output represents each list, so for example where an output has 4 container numbers, that's 4 dictionaries, I would like to access each number by dictionary.  How can this be done?

Code:

```
 k_container = ' '
    k_container_size = ' '
    container_info = " "
    for sr in Containers:
      if("La311Containers" in Containers):
        lcontainers311 = Containers ["La311Containers"]
        for Containers in lcontainers311:
            k_container_size_1= Containers['ContainerSize']
            k_container_type_1 = Containers['ContainerType']
            k_damage_lid_1 = Containers['DamageonLid']
            k_damage_axle_1 = Containers['DamageonAxle']
            k_damage_on_body_1 = Containers['DamageonBody']
            k_damage_on_handle_1 = Containers['DamageonHandleEndcap']
            k_damage_on_wheels_1 = Containers ['DamageonWheels']
            k_container_number_1= Containers['ContainerNumber']
            print k_container_number_1
```

Output:

```
r6b0102123456





r6g0145678900


R9B0127546869



R9B0707282828

r6b08789685


r9b0203060501

r9g0706423681

r6b01152687


r6b1234512345

r9g0102123456

r6b0102123456



n/a
n/a
n/a
n/a





r91234512345
r9123456789
rb12152586



3235658585


r6b12345


r6b1234512345


r9r0103454241

r9b0125783985

R9B1234512345









r6b0140345424

r6r0907879687
r6b0679050695





r9g0132358238

r6b0732430223


r9g4141258258
r9r0110565258
r6b0110654858

r9r0201030605
r9g0104050203
r6b0103454241

r6b0102030104

n/a
n/a

r6b0102030605


r6r660253

r9b022365



n/a
n/a
n/a



rb324556951


r9b0102030605

r9r0405060709



r9r5678234657

r9b365789201



r9r660253


r9b022365

r9r1234567


r9b0708123467


R9R1205786933



r9g0708454
r9r7894564


r6b0708945


R9B0708080809

R6B1234512345
R9G1234512345
R3b1234512345


n/a
n/a
n/a

r6g1789346527
r6r8902346571
r3b2398093876

R301021234512

r6b070785784
r9g0705454
r9r0708454

r6g01075563
r6r01052236
r6b025223

r3b1234567890

r6g01075563
r6r01052236
r3b025223

r3b4156951651

r9b1234512345

r9g0410506030
r6b0102040506

r3b9730281
r9g4679201
r9r3769820

R6B0707082828






















































r9g07126391
r9r07086542
r6b0708984656

r6b0102030605

R3B1234512345
R3B1234512345
R3B1234512345
R3B1234512345

R9g015233
r9r010532056
r6b02310

r9r010532056
r3g23534264
r6b02314

r9r1234512345
r9g1234512345
r6b1234512345

r6b0101456456

r9g02633
r9r01532056
r6b02310

r3b156985255
g3b4444546546
r3b122145211

r6b0708123456

R9R0125897897
R9G0127845645
R9R0128587778
r6b0187688454


R6B0701055828




r3b0101125542


n/a



R6B010523152

r6b2345743333

r6b015684876

n/a

r6b0115123123

n/a
n/a
n/a



Z9B0173248089
O6B548763

r9b070805456
```

Comment: Are you using the `json` module?

Comment: Yes, why is that relevant? I am using json.loads.

Comment: Because sometimes people think they have to parse JSON by hand. It's good that you're using the module. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so `lcontainers311` contains the list of dictionaries, and you want to retrieve only the 'ContainerNumber' value from the first dict in the list?

```
first_container_number = lcontainers311[0]['ContainerNumber']
```

aka

```
first_dict_idx = 0
first_container_number = lcontainers311[first_idx]['ContainerNumber']
```

Comment: This solution seemed to work, although I thought I tried it before, :$.  Thanks @tenwest.

Comment: eheh no problem, glad it helped.. n ested things can get tricky. if it solves it, please accept the answer :)